# GNU make: create targets baed on specific directory contents (1:1 target-directory mapping)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a series of directories organized like this:

```
foo/
    foo.file1 foo.file2
bar/
    bar.file1 bar.file2
baz/
    baz.file1 baz.file2
```

Right now I'm processing these files using a script that does all the checking for file existence etc but I thought that perhaps I could use a Makefile for it (since said script is very fragile), to avoid reprocessing files that did not change.

The problem is that each directory is independent, and I'd need to do, for example:

```
foo.file1.processed: foo.file1
      run_random_program foo.file1 -o foo.file1.processed
```

for each of the 71 directories that are in total in that path. This looks like being extremely tedious and I wonder if there's something that would prevent me from writing all of this by hand.

Is such a thing possible?

EDIT: Some examples that show what I have in mind, had I a single Makefile for each directory:

```
file1.cds.callable: file1.callable
    long_script_name -i $< -o $@

file1.rds: file1.cds.callable
    another_long_script_name $< additional_file_in_folder $@

file1.csv: file1.rds
    yet_another_script $< $@
```

Comment: Where do you place the `foo.file1.processed`? `foo/foo.file1` is input of the output `bar/bar.files`? Is there a rule to define `run_random_program`?

Comment: Is there any commonality or relation between directory or filenames and the processing steps they experience?

Comment: Answering both comments at once:

-  No, each directory is independent.
-  All the steps are identical per-directory, the name of the directory is directly related to the files within (same stem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html) are exactly what you need:

```
# These are the original source files (based on the example)
CALLABLE := $(wildcard */*.callable)

# These are the final targets
TARGETS := $(CALLABLE:%.callable=%.csv)

all: $(TARGETS)

%.csv : %.rds
        yet_another_script $< $@
%.rds: %.cds.callable
        another_long_script_name $< additional_file_in_folder $@
%.cds.callable: %.callable
        long_script_name -i $< -o $@
```